# Get the id of input using it's name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the id of input using it's name,and to empty the input field.But it's not working.Is it possible?

html:

```
<input type="text" id="1"  name="Color"   maxlength="2" />
```

jQuery:

```
var myId="#";
     myId=myId + $('[name="Color"]').attr('id');
   $($myId).var('');
```

Comment: `$myId` seems like a typo? Also, why do you want to get the ID if you already have a reference to the input?

Comment: Also if you are getting an input by its name to just turn around and select it by id is redundant. They would be selecting the same thing. And when using jQuery to change input values you use `val()` not `var()`

Comment: because I get only the name from select element(not in my question code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
let id = $('input[name$="Color"]').val('').attr('id');
console.log(id);
$(`#${id}`).val('');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="1"  name="Color"   maxlength="2" />
```

Comment: `const id = $('input[name="Color"]').val('').attr('id');` would be better. Not so clear why he'd want the id value when he has a reference to the input though.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the input value using the val() function.

```
<input type="text" id="1" name="Color" maxlength="2"/>

var myId='#' + $('[name="Color"]').attr('id');
$(myId).val('');
```

To get the input value use it like this:

```
$(myId).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
const myId = $('input[name="Color"]').attr('id');
$("#"+myId).val(''); // you can set any value here or you can perform any other operations on this element -> $("#"+myId)
```

On first line of this JS code, we are getting `id` attribute and then on second line, we're using to manipulate element.

Now, if you want `id` only for performing some operations on that `input` element, you don't need to get id. You can also do like this.

```
let elem = $('input[name="Color"]');
elem.val(''); // only if same name is not used anywhere else.
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr` directly to set a value. Moreover there is no need to append `#`.

```js
let element = $('[name="Color"]');
console.log("before", element.attr('id'));
element.attr('id', null);
console.log("after", element.attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="1"  name="Color"   maxlength="2" />
```